# Changing the value of a key in a Dictionary of key type string and value List of int

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, key

I have a `Dictionary` of key type `string` and value of `List<int>`, and I need to change the key `string` value while maintaining the `List<int>` values.

```
static void ChangeName(Dictionary<string, List<int>> studentGrades)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the student whose name you wish to change.");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (studentGrades.ContainsKey(input))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What would you like to change " + input + " to?");
        string newname = Console.ReadLine();
        studentGrades[input] = newname;
    }
}
```

I know that doing `studentGrades[input] = newname;` does not work as it is attempting to change the value of the `List<int>`. I am also uncertain if changing the value of a key is possible, what are some possible workarounds? I get error `CS0029` in `Visual Studio`.

Answer (score 2):

> A dictionary key cannot be modified

But you can solve this is another way.

- You are checking if the dictionary has your input, if it has the key, you are going to give it a new name but the value remains the same. So with the help of `TryGetValue` method first obtain the actual value.
- Then you will have to remove the old key and add a key with the `newName` which you will provide as input.

Just add the below piece inside your `ContainsKey` block

```
    studentGrades.TryGetValue(input, out var valToUpdate);
    studentGrades.Remove(input);
    studentGrades.Add(newName,valToUpdate);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can remove an entry with old key (`input`) and then add an entry with new key (`newname`):

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();

if (studentGrades.ContainsKey(input))
{
    string newname = Console.ReadLine();

    List<int> grades = studentGrades[input];
    studentGrades.Remove(input);        // Remove an entry with old key.
    studentGrades.Add(newname, grades); // Add an entry with new key.
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate it!